# Modelform is not populating its field with current values

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am making a view that will pre-populate its field incase if it is being edited again, otherwise serve a blank modelform.

```
def ViewProfile(request,slug):
ProfileResults=Profile.objects.filter(DiaryUser=slug)
if request.method=='POST':
    if Profile.objects.filter(DiaryUser=slug).exists():
        ProfileAlready=get_object_or_404(Profile,DiaryUser=slug)
        form=UpdateProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=ProfileAlready)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form=UpdateProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            ProfileUpdate=form.save(commit=False)
            ProfileUpdate.DiaryUser=slug
            ProfileUpdate.save()
    return redirect('Display',**{'slug':slug})
else:
    form=UpdateProfileForm()
    return render(request,'Mobile/ViewProfile.html',{'form':form,'slug':slug,'ProfileResults':ProfileResults})
```

but it is not pre-populting its fields otherwise it is working fine. Can anyone provide suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
def ViewProfile(request,slug):

    ProfileAlready=get_object_or_404(Profile,DiaryUser=slug)  # <-- Move this code in outer scope of POST request
    if request.method=='POST':
        # rest of the code
    else:
        form=UpdateProfileForm(instance=ProfileAlready)  # Pass instance here
        # rest of the code
```

Comment: sorry, But i can't understand what are you trying to convey

Comment: I have moved `ProfileAlready` outside of if condition. And I have passed it as instance in else block. Compare the answer with the question please

Comment: i mean it is not prepopulating the fields too